# Docker base image filesystem

Tags: docker

Docker can't modify base image's filesystem, but can't copy it. How can store its changes during container usage? I see that it stores files under `/var/lib/docker`, but how can store filesys' changes without modifying it? What is the methodology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does store changes through a new filesystem layer, because of its copy-on-write mechanism:

[image: https://www.softnas.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Feature-COW-Full.png]

Those changes disappear after a [`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/rm/) (unless you [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/) right after a [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/stop/))

If you want some persistence, you would need to use [a volume or use a data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

When doing a [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/), you can mount a volume from your host or mount one from a data container.